# PHPMyAdmin: "General relation features: Disabled"

Tags: configuration

I've been looking around for something like this for a while, and I've found some tips on similar issues, but not exactly the same. I really don't know what to do.

I downloaded and installed WAMP, and I have a MySQL and PHPMyAdmin setup according to common indications that can be found everywhere (securing MySQL root account, etc.).

When I log into PHPMyAdmin (either as root or as pma), I see the following message at the bottom of the page:

> The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated.
>   To find out why click here.

And when following the link, got a page with the following:

```
Server: localhost

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...  OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ...  OK
    General relation features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...  OK
    Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ...  OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...  OK
    Creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  OK
    Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
    Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled
    Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  OK
    SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] ...  OK
    Designer: Disabled
```

Somebody please explain to me, why the heck if all settings are "`OK`" the features remain "`Disabled`"?

Note: at first all the settings were "`not OK`" and I managed to add the settings to **config.inc.php**, and then created the tables using **scripts/create_tables.php**.

Of course I have already tried restarting the server or clearing the browser cache (several times, so I am sure the problem comes elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

I just had to logout and login to see the new features, try that